# Synonyms for docker-in-docker tags

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

We have three tags related to running docker in docker. (This is sometimes abbreviated to 'dind.') We should combine them into a single tag:

- [docker-dind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-dind)
- [dind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dind)
- [docker-in-docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-in-docker)

I think [docker-in-docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-in-docker) is the most clear tag out all of these, so the other two tags should point to it.

Thoughts?

Comment: why isn't it just `docker`?

Comment: Getting docker to properly run inside of docker is a particularly tricky situation for developers, and the issues you have running in that fashion are distinct from the ones you have just running in docker regularly. It makes sense to have a dedicated tag. It'll never be particularly large of a tag, but as people move to containerized development environments I think it'll become more and more common to see people having questions about it.

Comment: It's analogous to nested virtualization.

Answer (score 25):

I concur that those are three similarly related tags and that docker-in-docker is the clearest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I agree that all three tags should point to the same.

The `docker-in-docker` tag could also be relevant to people attempting to access the Docker daemon or other services within a container without actually using `dind`, for example questions on using [this image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker), which is not the same as dind.

Comment: Are you saying that `dind` is the name of a specific tool, so some people might be running Docker-in-Docker, but not using that specific tool named `dind`?

Comment: @CodyGray actually, i think `dind` represents [the image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker)

Comment: but "this image" *is* the same as `dind`.

Comment: I may be mistaken here, but if you take a look at the [tags](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker?tab=tags) for that image, the same image has got variants with and without `dind` in the tag name. This is what made me think that `docker-in-docker` was not the same as `dind`.

Comment: I understand "Docker in Docker" (or, for short, "DinD") to be a technical term that literally means running a second Docker daemon inside a container.  Even though it's occasionally referred to as such, bind-mounting the host's Docker socket is _not_ DinD.

Comment: @Dakshin The dind image has a wrapper script designed to set up some mountpoints. See the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/30d7b9bf7663c96fcd888bd75e9aaa547a808a23/20.10/dind/Dockerfile) and [wrapper script](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/hack/dind). It also sets an environment variable which disables apparmor.